# $a\in \mathbb{C}$ for which $[ \mathbb{Q}(a) : \mathbb{Q}(a^3) ] = 2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I want to find a $a\in \mathbb{C}$ for which $[ \mathbb{Q}(a) : \mathbb{Q}(a^3) ] = 2$. 
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $a$ be a primitive cube root of unity.